# laravel Dompdf large pdf generation issues and TCPDF is not installing

Tags: laravel, pdf, tcpdf, dompdf

I am using laravel Dompdf package for pdf generation but it is giving me error **504 Gateway Time-out** when pdf is too long or it has more data for calculations. i have increased the timeout and memory limit but no result :(

```
 - Installation request for elibyy/tcpdf-laravel 5.2.0 -> satisfiable by elibyy/tcpdf-laravel[5.2.0].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.1
- elibyy/tcpdf-laravel 5.2.0 requires illuminate/support 5.2.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
```

now i am installing TCPDF that it may work with large pdf generation but it is giving me installation error. i have checked the logs file but it does not have any error related to invoice pdf.

[image]

any help?

Comment: Please provide the errors you are getting from PDF generation with DomPDF (a 504 means something is wrong on the server, so post the relevant error from the PHP error log) and more informations about how you installed TCPDF and what error your got.

Comment: while installation it is showing

 - Installation request for elibyy/tcpdf-laravel 5.2.0 -> satisfiable by elibyy/tcpdf-laravel[5.2.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.1
    - elibyy/tcpdf-laravel 5.2.0 requires illuminate/support 5.2.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0

Comment: Please update your question and use proper code formatting.

Comment: i have updated my question